# Issues with OleObjects in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I have a random problem related to OleObjects.

I have developed some code to upgrade a set of user sheets. The routine copies and pastes tabs from one of the sheets, using:

```
Convert_V1toV2 ThisWorkbook
```

When I then want to put it into practice, then the code opens the sheet concerned and the same code is called, so it gives something like this:

```
set wb = Workbooks.Open(...
Convert_V1toV2 wb
```

In this code, I have to create `Forms.OptionButton.1` type ObjectOle. The code works in the first case, and crashes in the second case, with the message:

> Error 1004 Unable to get Object Property of OLEObject class

I set up a test to anticipate this crash:

```vb
Function oloTest(wb as Workbook)
    Dim olo as OleObject
    ...    
    Set olo = ws.OleObjects("oTitle_Type_ProductPart")
    olo.Activate
    ...
End Function
```

The first instruction works, but the second hangs (error 1004), as well as if I ask for `olo.Name` or other properties. It's the same on two machines.
I looked it up on the Internet. Deleting `MSForm.exd` does not change the case. All other explanations fall because it works well in one of the two contexts.

By dint of searching, I finished to have `oloTest()=True`, **if the sheet is put in the foreground**.... That's nonsense. Now the conversion test passes, but once in a while there is a sheet that returns a strange crash (a compile error: "*Only comments can appear after End Sub, etc*." then leading to "*Error &h80010108 The Object method of OleObject has failed*" while my worksheet at that time still has no code at all). This happens when my OleObjects are created and I want to assign a value to them `ws.OLEObjects("oComittee_Classification_Stand").Object = True`, when I can read them...

This conversion involves hundreds of sheets and it is an operator that will have to apply them. I would therefore like a stable solution. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you want a *stable* solution, I can only suggest you stop using activex controls.

Comment: That's certainly very good advice, thank you. I have considered it, but then I will have to be satisfied with the form controls, which are quite poor.  Do you see anything else?

Comment: It's basically those and shapes, unless you want to/can use a userform as a 'control panel'. But activex controls never have been stable and probably never will be. And of course they don't work on Macs at all.

Comment: Thank you, I needed a clear-cut opinion like this. I'll probably spend less time doing code to turn OleObjects into UserForms than I lost time bypassing the instabilities of the former. Can you tell me here if the UserForms Excel are absolutely identical for any Office application (I only find a Microsoft Reference for Access)?

Comment: Userforms are the same, and not the same as Access Forms (Access also has regular userforms though)

Answer (score 1):

I had to work on the conversion of another one of my applications for a customer. The amazing fact is that *I encountered exactly the same type of problem* with sheets containing only `Userforms` and not a single `ActiveX` control.

Some of the workbooks I had to convert had crashes very similar to what I described in my initial message as soon as I coded these objects, even though there were less than 10 simple buttons per sheet and nothing else.

This suggests to me that I wasn't necessarily dealing with a crash of the `ActiveX`, but maybe with a crash of their container, the Shapes, or at least that the `Userforms` are no more reliable than the `ActiveX`.

*This contradicts Rory's initial answer that I should do without `ActiveX`*.

This is the first point of my answer. The second point that supports the first is that I managed to repair the damage: over 800 sheets were converted on site without this particular crash happening again.

**The solution was presented in the problem statement: in tab copy mode the crash did not occur**.

The Excel repair (`CorruptLoad:= xlRepairFile`) didn't work, so I experimented a personal repair using the `WorkSheet.Copy` command I was using in development mode, and it worked. I won't describe here the drawbacks of this command, that's another subject.
I tell myself that this command must read each element of the source `WorkSheet` with a requirement, a reliability and an exhaustiveness that the repair does not know: corrupted Shapes objects do not make it crash and moreover are corrected in the destination, whether they are `Userforms` or `ActiveX`.

As an aside and without really finding a cause and effect link, I found in both developments that the `WorkBooks` I had to convert had the `KeepChangeHistory` property to true. This had given me an absolutely incoherent error message when I created a `WorkSheet` by code which had put me the chip in my ear. But, if unchecking this property did not fix the problem, there is no indication that it was not the property that triggered it.

I would like to point out that these two developments have been made by generations of non-developers, from the trainee to the user, and that I took them back like so many spaghetti packages to be unraveled, because it had become impossible to make them evolve, this to say that I don't know their history nor what really corrupted them.